# Can I use a Twisted GTK Reactor with a UDP Receiver?

Tags: python, gtk, twisted

I want to add a UDP receiver:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class UDP(DatagramProtocol):

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
    #Receive a string "X Y" and add to plot.    
    print "Received %r from %s:%d" % (data, host, port)

reactor.listenUDP(9999, UDP())
reactor.run()
```

To my existing matplotlib code that uses a GTKReactor:

```
from matplotlib import use
use('GTK')
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.backends import backend_gtk
from twisted.internet import gtk2reactor
gtk2reactor.install()

from twisted.internet import reactor, task

class TwistedGtkShow(backend_gtk.Show):
    running = False
    def mainloop(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.running = True
            reactor.run()

def onclick(event):
  print 'Clicked: %d, X=%d, Y=%d, Xdata=%f, Ydata=%f' % (event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)

def onpress(event):
  print "Pressed: ", event.key


def main():
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4])
    pyplot.ylabel('Numbers')

    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onpress)

    def proof():
        print 'Twisted!'
    task.LoopingCall(proof).start(3)

    TwistedGtkShow()()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But they are both none blocking? How can I run both of them and update the plot as well as respond to click events and potentially send UDP packets back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it.

All you have to be careful to do is not call `reactor.run()` twice.  `reactor.run()` is the blocking API in Twisted (it blocks until your program is over).